# what kind of adders and multipliers architectures are used in IEEE.numeric_std.all

Tags: vhdl

hi every bod y i would like to know what kind of adders and multipliers architectures are used in IEEE.numeric_std.all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "what kind"? The numeric_std package defines the *interface* in terms of VHDL functions (or operators) for adding and multiplying, and it defines the *behavior* as simple 32-bit integer arithmetic.

The actual *implementation in terms of gates* does not concern the numeric_std package. Your synthesis tool will choose an appropriate implementation for you, which will be OK most of the time. Or you can configure your tool to choose an implementation that you want. Refer to the documentation of your synthesis tool for more info on how to do that.

Comment: can you give me more explanation for example when i build a module I am the one that define its architecture specially if I am writing a rtl vhdl so the synthesis tool will only "translate" this architecture to a gate level presentation and will not affect the architecture .